# I can't deploy my API Nodejs app on heroku

Tags: node.js, express

I deployed my Node API app on Heroku. Deployed is successful but when I check logs showing these errors? I searched on google I can't find any useful. Please suggest what should I do??

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vllvv.png"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vllvv.png%22)

Edit: I just solve it.

Comment: It's very hard to judge from the info you provide, but this likely means your application throws a runtime error on (any?) request and crashes. Check the logs for uncaught exceptions and try to fix their root cause before deploying again.

Comment: @m90 I have mentioned the logs images links above I can't post images due to low reputations.

Comment: H10 error can occur due to different reasons. How are you deploying it to the heroku did you used any build script? I got this error when my app.listen code was out of the build scope.

Comment: You can always post the text version of your log output. Copy the relevant log output from the Heroku console and include it in your question.

Comment: @Ashutoshpatole I didn't use any build script.Here my Github link https://github.com/hareom284/Memories

Comment: Which one are you deploying client or server ? @ZawZawWin

Comment: @Ashutoshpatole I am deploying server part only first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package.json file is missing the start script and make sure that your mongodb atlas is allowing connections to only your ip address in development. do not allow it to everyone as 0.0.0.0

```
{
    "name": "server",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js",   // <== add this above your "dev: xxxx," line
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "mongoose": "^6.0.10"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.13"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help I just solve it by changing the MongoDB database access URL to access from anywhere then it will work and also I changed the package.json above you descript

Comment: If it helped then do consider it upvoting and marking it as correct answer. :)